# Error when trying to convert 2-channels sound file to mono using sox or ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, sox

When I tried:

```
sox file.wav -c 1 file.wav
```

I got:

```
sox WARN wav: Premature EOF on .wav input file
```

When I tried:

```
ffmpeg -i file.wav -ac 1 file.wav
```

I got:

```
[pcm_s16le @ 0x2997880] Invalid PCM packet, data has size 2 but at least a size of 4 was expected
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Comment: Please always post the full, uncut command line output, not just the warnings or errors you think are relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in using the same file as input and output.

Comment: thanks, please accept your own answer. That was the problem